# c# backgroundworker stops when using a linq statement

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker that runs a sequential tasks which leads up to this portion of the code and stops here. Was wondering if I can get anyone's help on this?

Thanks.

```
Output = Source.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<int>("Hierarchy") == h)
                        .Select(g =>
                        {
                            var row = Output.NewRow();

                            row[0] = g.Field<int>("Id");
                            row[1] = g.Field<int>("Id");

                            for (int counter = 2; counter < Output.Columns.Count; counter++)
                            {
                                row[counter] = g.Field<double>(counter);
                            }

                            return row;
                        }
                        ).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Try commenting the background worker and executing the code on ui thread, your problem has to be an exception in your code.

Comment: Please provide more of your code. This is not enough information to determine what your error is.

Comment: Run it in your debugger with _break on exception thrown_ enabled for all managed exceptions

Comment: the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` has a property: `Error` you can check it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler and it will tell you an error message. Please post it to get more information